# json parsing with groovy collect values

Tags: json, parsing, groovy

I have following json text and my goal is to find if any of the "direct" field has value 'false' for meta.name="name1"

I can parse and get list for "name1" but not sure how to go further.. like collect values of field "direct" != true and check if collection is more than 0.

```
def list = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(text )
println list.record.land.find{ it.meta.name == 'name1' } 



{
  "version": 1,
  "record": {
    "land": [
      {
        "meta": {
          "name": "name1",
          "type": "person"
        },
        "delete": {
          "result": "allow",
          "factor": {
            "direct": true,
            "rules": [
              {
                "rule1": "1002",
                "uri": "/deeds/567576-ffgt-1002"
              },
              {
                "rule1": "5012",
                "uri": "/deeds/567576-dfge-5012"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "transfer": {
          "result": "allow",
          "factor": {
            "direct": true,
            "rules": [
              {
                "rule1": "1002",
                "uri": "/deeds/567576-ffgt-1002"
              },
              {
                "rule1": "5012",
                "uri": "/deeds/567576-dfge-5012"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
         "move": {
          "result": "allow",
          "factor": {
            "direct": false,
            "rules": [
              {
                "rule1": "1002",
                "uri": "/deeds/567576-ffgt-1002"
              },
              {
                "rule1": "5012",
                "uri": "/deeds/567576-dfge-5012"
              }
            ]
          }
        }

  }
  ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first step you can filter json to find all objects with specifi name:

```
def filtered = list.record.land.findAll{ it.meta.name == 'name1'}
```

Then you could something like this:

```
def directIsFalse = ['delete', 'transfer', 'move'].any{
     filtered[it].factor.direct[0] == false;
}
```

This would return true if in at least one section ("delete", "transfer" or "move") field direct will be equal to `false`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: we can do more of the work in the findAll closure: `def hasFalseDirect = list.record.land.findAll {it.meta.name == "name1" && it.find {item -> item.value.factor?.direct == false}}`

Comment: If the keys in the 'filtered' list is dynamic (I mean can be any string.. not predefined like 'delete', 'update', etc), is there a way to check all?